# Pass existing object to constructor or construct a new one

Tags: c++, arduino

The easiest way for me to explain this is with an example of what i'm trying to do in a language which im more familiar with, C#:

```
public class ServerLib {
    private SoftwareSerial _bt;
    private string _name, _game;

    public ServerLib(int rx, int tx, string name, string game) {
        _bt = new SoftwareSerial(rx, tx);
        _bt.begin(9600);
        _name = name;
        _game = game;
    }

    public ServerLib(ref SoftwareSerial bt, string name, string game) {
        _bt = bt;
        _name = name;
        _game = game;
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to do this in an Arduino library (so I assume C++) and have tried the following things:

```
class ServerLib {
    public:
        ServerLib(int rx, int tx, String name, String game);
        ServerLib(SoftwareSerial serial, String name, String game);
    private:
        SoftwareSerial _bt;
        String _name;
        String _game;
};


ServerLib::ServerLib(int rx, int tx, String name, String game) : _bt(rx, tx) {
    _name = name;
    _game = game;

    _bt.begin(9600);
}

ServerLib::ServerLib(SoftwareSerial serial, String name, String game) : _bt(serial) {
    _name = name;
    _game = game;
}
```

This compiles but only the first constructor works, if I use the second one all attempts at using the SoftwareSerial seem to do nothing.
If I comment out the first constructor and replace the second one with

```
ServerLib::ServerLib(SoftwareSerial& serial, String name, String game) : _bt(serial) {}
```

And change the field to `SoftwareSerial& _bt` then this constructor will work fine, but I cannot manage to get it to compile with both constructors. If I keep it as is I get the error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'SoftwareSerial&' from expression of type 'int'
```

Changing the first constructor to

```
ServerLib::ServerLib(int rx, int tx, String name, String game) : _bt(SoftwareSerial(rx, tx)) {}
```

Errors with

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'SoftwareSerial&' from an rvalue of type 'SoftwareSerial'
```

The last thing I tried was moving the initialization inside of the first constructor like so:

```
ServerLib::ServerLib(int rx, int tx, String name, String game) {
    _bt = SoftwareSerial(rx, tx);
    _bt.begin(9600);
}
```

But this results in

```
error: uninitialized reference member 'ServerLib::_bt' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: The errors you are getting to not correspond to the code you have uploaded. How are you calling the constructor?

Comment: Why is `_bt` a reference in your real code? A "reference" in C++ is a completely different beast than a "reference" in C#. They only happen to be named using the same word.

Comment: The errors I posted are on those lines, I'm calling the constructor as `ServerLib server(10, 11, "name", "game");` or `ServerLib server(bt, "name", "game");` where `SoftwareSerial bt(10, 11);`

Answer (score 0):

In C# you're passing Serial by reference but in C++ this is actually a copy. So you're getting a brand new Serial object that presumably isn't "open".

I would make _bt a std::unique_ptr, create it with _bt = std::make_unique and pass it like that (with std::move) or use std::shared_ptr if it's needed elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, the reason I'm trying to pass it as reference is because the ServerLib object peeks into the SoftwareSerial to see if there's any bytes it should handle, if not it'll leave it untouched for the actual code to handle what's in the buffer.

Comment: If you make _bt a smart pointer you can return a const reference (or pointer) to it for the "peek", pass one in with std::move in the constructor or create one yourself with std::make_unique in your other constructor.